# Azure - Service Health alert fired but alert emails not received

Tags: azure, azure-alerts

I created a Service Health alert to fire whenever Azure Data Factory was experiencing any issue from their side.

I have been creating alerts for other services of Azure but somehow only the one for Service Health is not working, even though the history log said that the alert was "fired" the last few days. I ran the test with "Service Health" sample type and it was also not working, even though for other sample types it did send me the test alert email.

My setup for the action group and the alert rule is really simple: send email notification whenever Service Health was showing issue with Data Factory. Here is the json code for the action group setup

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "actionGroups_Adf_alert_actiongroup_name": {
        "defaultValue": "Adf-alert-actiongroup",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('actionGroups_Adf_alert_actiongroup_name')]",
        "location": "GermanyWestCentral",
        "properties": {
            "groupShortName": "Adf-alert-ac",
            "enabled": true,
            "emailReceivers": [
                {
                    "name": "TeamName_-EmailAction-",
                    "emailAddress": "TeamName@mycompany.com",
                    "useCommonAlertSchema": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "MyName_-EmailAction-",
                    "emailAddress": "MyName@mycompany.com",
                    "useCommonAlertSchema": false
                }
            ],
            "smsReceivers": [],
            "webhookReceivers": [],
            "eventHubReceivers": [],
            "itsmReceivers": [],
            "azureAppPushReceivers": [],
            "automationRunbookReceivers": [],
            "voiceReceivers": [],
            "logicAppReceivers": [],
            "azureFunctionReceivers": [],
            "armRoleReceivers": []
        }
    }
]
```

Any suggestion for what might have gone wrong in my setup? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that "Enable the common alert schema" has to be turned on for the alert to work. Very simple but quite easy to overlook.